# Nagios - difference between 'CURRENT SERVICE STATE' & 'SERVICE ALERT'

Tags: nagios, alerts

I am a newbie to Nagios. I googled quite a bit and read documents related to states, notifications and so on. But I did not find answer for my questions.
Could you please help me understand the difference between 'CURRENT SERVICE STATE' & 'SERVICE ALERT'.

Background:
In our Nagios screen all the hosts and their related services are displayed properly. We are planning to use nagios.log for additional tasks.

In nagios.log file, I see that there is CURRENT SERVICE STATE and SERVICE ALERT log lines which contain the necessary information that we need.
I have few questions.

1. What is the difference between 'CURRENT SERVICE STATE' & 'SERVICE
   ALERT'?
2. Deep diving into the log file, i noticed that CURRENT SERVICE STATE is logged only once at 00:00 AM. Where as the SERVICE ALERT is logged randomly (There is no constant time gap between log entries for a particular Service Check)
3. Even though the checks are scheduled to run every 5 minutes, the status.dat file has entries every few seconds. This makes it hard to achieve what we need. Since single service check run info is logged multiple times.
4. Sometimes tail -f on nagios.log stops the log file from updating further. What could be the reason for this?
5. In one setup nagios.log file is updated every 10 minutes and in one setup it is very random. IS there any configuration to handle the update schedule?

Thanks,

Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

1) CURRENT SERVICE STATE is the current state of the service (OK, WARNING, CRITICAL, or UNKNOWN). SERVICE ALERT will only be logged if the state of a service changes.

2) The logging of CURRENT SERVICE STATE at midnight is something to do with how your server is set up. Again, SERVICE ALERT is random because it will alert at a state change.

3) status.dat is refreshed every time a new cfg is applied. It will be updated every time a check is performed so you must have checks going out for multiple services which amounts to every few seconds. https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html

4) Either nagios.log is not updating or there is something wrong with your server's linux.

5) nagios.log is only updated when a change occurs in a host or service.